# Numpy array how to get index of row minimum

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array like this one

```
# [[0.64809866 1.4297429  1.76778859]
#  [0.98994126 0.60583935 1.07312068]
#  [0.47607127 0.58659789 1.52184562]
#  [0.6905903  0.33424117 1.50113122]
#  [0.66848235 1.5608329  2.02750987]
```

I'd like to find the min of each row, but knowing by index. Like this

```
# [[0]
#  [1]
#  [0]
#  [1]
#  [0]]
```

i used `np.min(dist, axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)` in order to generate a matrix with the min of results, but no idea how to follow from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `argmin`

```
a.argmin(axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
array([[0],
       [1],
       [0],
       [1],
       [0]])
```

Comment: I think I wasn't clear, sorry. I wanted to find the index which is the min value from `X1, X2, X3` (my matrix X) so I can create a new one matrix witch every index of every minium value of every row and then concatenate to the original matrix. Sorry for my english

Comment: @Sharki check the update , the you need `np.hstack([a,a.argmin(axis=1).reshape(-1,1)])
`